# Exception occur while executing broker commands in IBM ACE

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

**mqsistop <NODE-NAME**>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.broker.jmsclienthelper.JMSClientHelper

```
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:410)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.ClassLoadingUtils.getClasses(ClassLoadingUtils.java:60)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.broker.jmsclienthelper.JMSClientHelper

```
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:945)

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:890)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.ReverseDelegationClassLoader.findClass(ReverseDelegationClassLoader.java:130)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.BrokerClassLoader.findClass(BrokerClassLoader.java:372)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:945)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:890)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.JavaResourceClassLoader.loadClass(JavaResourceClassLoader.java:579)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.ReverseDelegationClassLoader.findClass(ReverseDelegationClassLoader.java:130)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.WebServicesClassLoader.findClass(WebServicesClassLoader.java:255)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:945)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:890)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:873)

    at com.ibm.broker.classloading.JavaResourceClassLoader.loadClass(JavaResourceClassLoader.java:579)

    ... 3 more
```

**BIP4374S**: An unexpected exception has occurred in the Java API framework.

An internal processing error has occurred.

This is an internal error. Contact your IBM support center.

**BIP8081E**: An error occurred while processing the command.

An error occurred while the command was running; the command has cleaned up and ended.

Use messages prior to this one to determine the cause of the error.

Check for some common problems:

Does the user id have the correct authorities (for example a member of the mqbrkrs group)?

Is any operating system limit set too low to allow the command to run?

Is the environment correctly set up?

Correct the problem and retry the command, otherwise, contact your IBM support center.